# How to specify root for installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

I'm trying to install Ubuntu. My system have pre-installed Windows 8. I made USB bootable and then I booted into Ubuntu from there and I am in TRY Ubuntu mode now, I am having a problem in installing Ubuntu. When I attempt install Ubuntu then it says:

> No root file system is defined.  Correct this from the
>   partitioning menu.

Comment: What do you want to do with the Windows system? Replace it?

Comment: No i want both windows and ubuntu to run side by side

Comment: Don't you have a "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option?

Comment: I couldn't find any solution to my problem. can you please brief me a bit. I have set the password for root , now just that how can I define root file and what actually defining a root file means ?

Comment: The *root file system* is where you should install the root of the file system, the base of the ubuntu installation, not the root user. For example a path in Ubuntu looks like this: `/home/user/music` so the root is `/`

Comment: How can I define the root file?

Comment: Using the partitioning menu. Check out this link for more information: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: sorry for duplication, but I was not able to find this. @Fabby, a good link on the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which partition will be root (represented with an slash `/`) in the partitioning screen. If you don't know how to do this **go back twice, and select the automatic installation** (the one that doesn't say "Something else...).

To specify the root partition you have to be in the partitioning screen, select the partition where you will install Ubuntu, and then click "Change...". You will be presented with the following:

[image: Thanks to Mateo]

Here, in mount point you should select `/`, click ok, check again everything, and then continue.